# automatic capital letter at the beginning of a word when typing in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, vb.net-to-c#

I would like to create a function when typing in textbox the beginning of each sentence automatically becomes large.

I've been unsuccessfully trying to make with VB.Net, but when I tried with C # can not run properly.

I do not know where my mistake, I hope anyone of you can help improve my C# code thank you.

My Function In Class C# (failed) :

```
    class ClsText
{
    public int Current_Point = 0;
    public bool Remove_Handle = false;
    public string tulis(string text)
    {
        string[] validasi_char = new string[] { " ", ".", "(", ")", "!", "@", "$", "%", "&", "*", "/", "?", "+", "-", ",", ">", "<", "'", "~", "`" };
        string str_temp = "";

        foreach (string vchar in validasi_char)
        {
            string[] split_temp = text.Split(validasi_char,StringSplitOptions.);
            str_temp = "";
            foreach (string txt in split_temp)
            {
                str_temp = str_temp + txt.Substring(0,0).ToUpper() + txt.Substring(1, txt.Length) + vchar;
            }
            text = str_temp.Substring(0, str_temp.Length - 1);
        }
        text = text.Substring(0, 0).ToUpper() + text.Substring(1, text.Length);
        return text;
    }
}
```

My code in textbox C# (failed) :

```
            ClsText asd = new ClsText();
        if (asd.Remove_Handle == true) 
        {
           asd.Current_Point = textEdit1.SelectionStart;
           asd.Remove_Handle = true;
           textEdit1.Text = asd.tulis(textEdit1.Text);

        }
        textEdit1.Select(asd.Current_Point, 2);
```

My Function In VB.NET (success) :

```
    Public current_point As Integer = 0
    Public remove_handle As Boolean = False
    Public Function Tulis(ByVal Text As String) As String
    Dim validasi_char() As String = {" ", ".", "(", ")", "!", "@", "$", "%", "&", "*", "/", "?", "+", "-", ",", ">", "<", """", "'", "~", "`"}
    Dim str_temp As String = ""
    For Each vchar In validasi_char
        Dim split_temp() As String = Split(Text, vchar)
        str_temp = ""
        For Each txt In split_temp
            str_temp = str_temp + Mid(txt, 1, 1).ToUpper + Mid(txt, 2, txt.Length) + vchar
        Next
        Text = Mid(str_temp, 1, str_temp.Length - 1)
    Next
    Text = Mid(Text, 1, 1).ToUpper + Mid(Text, 2, Text.Length)
    Return Text
End Function
```

My code in textbox VB.Net (success) :

```
    Private Sub TextEdit1_EditValueChanging(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs) Handles TextEdit1.EditValueChanging
    If remove_handle = True Then GoTo DoCurrentPoint
    current_point = TextEdit1.SelectionStart
    remove_handle = True

    TextEdit1.Text = Tulis(TextEdit1.Text)
```

DoCurrentPoint:
        remove_handle = False
        TextEdit1.Select(current_point, 0)
    End Sub

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/uppercase-first-letter

Comment: Do not post a video. Post your actual error message in the body of your question.

Comment: I do not have an error message, oke i remove a video

Answer (score 1):

Used ToTitleCase from CurrentCulture.TextInfo

```
public void textB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyTextbox.Text = ToTitleCase(MyTextbox.Text);
}

public static string ToTitleCase(string stringToConvert)
{
  return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(stringToConvert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit confused, but from what I understand you are trying to auto-capitalise the first letter of anything that is typed in a textbox.

Here is some code for a function in c# that accepts a string and returns a string so formatted

```
public string AutoCapitalize(string text)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? "" : text.Length > 1 ? text[0].ToString().ToUpper() + text.Substring(1) : text[0].ToString().ToUpper();
}
```

Then on the TextChanged event of your textbox you could call it like so:

Edit: _isCapitalizaingMyTextbox would be a private bool declared on your form

```
public void MyTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isCapitalizaingMyTextbox)
    {
        _isCapitalizaingMyTextbox = true;
        MyTextbox.Text = AutoCapitalize(MyTextbox.Text);
        _isCapitalizaingMyTextbox = false;
    }
}
```

Edit: based on MikeH comments I've added some code to prevent endless loops in the TextChanged handler

Comment: That'll cause an endless loop.  You may want `if (MyTextbox.Text !=AutoCapitalize(MyTextbox.Text))` within your `TextChanged` event

Comment: I've tried and did not work at the first type all letters to upper and like typing from right to left. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you put the following code in your TextBox's `TextChanged` event-handler, it will give you the desired results:

```
Private Sub YourTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim Pos = YourTextBox.SelectionStart
    Dim Len = YourTextBox.SelectionLength

    YourTextBox.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(YourTextBox.Text, "(?<G1>[,.,(,),!,,$,%,&,*,/,?,+,-,,,>,<,,',~,`] *)(?<G2>[a-z])", Function(m) m.Groups(1).Value & m.Groups(2).Value.ToUpper())

    YourTextBox.SelectionStart = Pos
    YourTextBox.SelectionLength = Len
End Sub
```

In C#:

```
private void YourTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var Pos = YourTextBox.SelectionStart;
    var Len = YourTextBox.SelectionLength;

    YourTextBox.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(YourTextBox.Text, "(?<G1>[,.,(,),!,,$,%,&,*,/,?,+,-,,,>,<,,',~,`] *)(?<G2>[a-z])", m => m.Groups(1).Value + m.Groups(2).Value.ToUpper());

    YourTextBox.SelectionStart = Pos;
    YourTextBox.SelectionLength = Len;
}
```

Comment: Added C# version. FYI: There are many free online/offline tools that can convert between C# and VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are looking for. You want the textbox to automatically capitalize the first letter of every sentence. I have a solution that should work for your intended desire. First you have to create the OnTextBoxChanged event:

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox myTextArea = (sender as TextBox);
    if (myTextArea.Text.Length > 3)
    {
        char period = myTextArea.Text.ElementAtOrDefault(myTextArea.Text.Length - 3);
        char space = myTextArea.Text.ElementAtOrDefault(myTextArea.Text.Length - 2);
        char newestCharAdded = myTextArea.Text.Last();

        if(period == '.' && space == ' ' && char.IsLetter(newestCharAdded))
        {
            CapitalizeFunction(myTextArea, newestCharAdded);
        }

    }
    else if (myTextArea.Text.Length == 1)
    {
        char newestCharAdded = myTextArea.Text.Last();

        if(char.IsLetter(newestCharAdded))
        {
            CapitalizeFunction(myTextArea, newestCharAdded);                    
        }

    }

}
```

This will monitor all characters entered within a text box, and identify the end of a sentence by a period. It would be easy enough to incorporate more characters for the punctuation. I also incorporated the first character a user for enter for consistency. Here is the support function:

```
private void CapitalizeFunction(TextBox myTextArea, char newestCharAdded)
{
    // Take out the lowercase letter
    myTextArea.Text = myTextArea.Text.Remove(myTextArea.Text.LastIndexOf(newestCharAdded), 1) + char.ToUpper(newestCharAdded);

    // Returns the focus to the end of the string
    myTextArea.SelectionStart = myTextArea.Text.Length;
    myTextArea.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

The good part about this code is that you can use this for RichTextBox as well by just changing the appropriate types. Now that you have the event you just need to tie it to the desired textbox like this:

```
MyTextBox.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
```

Comment: Did you attach the event handler in your Form constructor? Did it just not work, or did it crash?